# config linux router to allow ftp

Tags: linux, centos, routing, vmware-esxi, ftp

I recently setup ESXi on a dedicated server and I tied to use /29 IP subnet for my VMs, due to datacenter policies I have to run A router-VM on my ESXi to route traffic to/from VMs.

I get a single IP address and 8IP subnet data center routed the subnet IP to my single IP, I configed my router-VM as following:

- assign the single IP to eth0 assign the first usable IP of subnet to
- eth1 enable kernel ip4 forwarding of router-VM (centOS 6.4) change
- the IP table to allow forwarding (just remove forward block rule). I
- used the IP of eth1 (first usable IP of subnet) for my VMs gateway I
- didn't add any route to router-VM, Just IP Forwarding.

Now every thing work properly, HTTP, SSH to server and from server to the Internet,
**except FTP server**, I disabled IP table of router VM completely but nothing changed.

I don't know what is source of my problem and how should I solve the problem.

Comment: for clearing I want routing because my VMs should be accessing publicly and I can ping my VMs IP and also ping outside world from my VMs. And The Ftp client stop after ftp command PASV (changing to passive mode)

Comment: Why do people go into colo/dedicated server scenarios where they don't have firewall or router options?

Comment: **Actually It wasn't a routing problem, my Ftp Server needs ip_conntrack_ftp module to be loaded.**

@ewwhite, every solution is not enterprise, somebody needs cheap soho solutions, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you load ip_nat_ftp and ip_conntrack_ftp modules?

```
# modprobe ip_nat_ftp 
# modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
```

Comment: I didn't load this modules, but after running this command nothing changed. for clearing I want routing because my VMs should be accessing publicly and I can ping my VMs IP and also ping outside world from my VMs. The Ftp client stop after ftp command PASV (changing to passive mode)

Comment: Did you load it on the router-vm?

Comment: I think I misunderstood, I ran _modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp_ on router-vm and didn't work. But it fixed after loading  **ip_conntrack_ftp** on my Ftp server. I was not a routing problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For permanent load of this modules I change the IPTABLES_MODULES option of iptables-config file 
`IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_nat_ftp ip_conntrack_ftp"`